# "site requires javascript" return as keywords from analysers

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, .htaccess, seo

I made a website using one of the free bootstrap site builder (Mobirise), while the codes looks messy and likely used too much unnecessary javascript, the site looks fine on browser and not sluggish.

However, when I analyse it with one of the free seo analyser, all of them return saying I have no description or title, even though the code definitely have it, and comes up with keywords such as "site requires javascript" and "please enable javascript".

From some of the tools that render the site as well, it usually just render the navigation bar only without the remaining content.

I tried to target it by searching those keyword phrases in the files and see if one of the javascript library acting funny and give those warnings but those phrases are not to be find within any files. So my deduction is it is a browser or server issued warning.

What is the issue here and how may I solve it? If it indeed is a coding issue, how do I know which javascript library is at fault?

The site is [here](http://viviennelawmakeup.com)

The tools I have been using includes[this](http://neilpatel.com/seo-analyzer/)  [& this](https://seositecheckup.com/) [& this](http://www.seowebpageanalyzer.com/)

Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no coding issue with your site, it's more a problem you need to see with your hosting provider.

Without user agent header, a visitor gets 403 error:

```
$ curl 'http://viviennelawmakeup.com/'  
<html>
<head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>403 Forbidden</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

With a user agent, it gets this (note the part where it says "This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your browser or use a browser with Javascript support"):

```
$ curl -s 'http://viviennelawmakeup.com/' -H 'User-Agent: FakeUserAgent'
<html><body><script type="text/javascript" src="/aes.js" ></script><script>function toNumbers(d){var e=[];d.replace(/(..)/g,function(d){e.push(parseInt(d,16))});return e}function toHex(){for(var d=[],d=1==arguments.length&&arguments[0].constructor==Array?arguments[0]:arguments,e="",f=0;f<d.length;f++)e+=(16>d[f]?"0":"")+d[f].toString(16);return e.toLowerCase()}var a=toNumbers("f655ba9d09a112d4968c63579db590b4"),b=toNumbers("98344c2eee86c3994890592585b49f80"),c=toNumbers("18fc59896ba5a77d84e6593224fe7c9a");document.cookie="__test="+toHex(slowAES.decrypt(c,2,a,b))+"; expires=Thu, 31-Dec-37 23:55:55 GMT; path=/"; location.href="http://viviennelawmakeup.com/?i=1";</script><noscript>This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your browser or use a browser with Javascript support</noscript></body></html>
```

I've tested with a "real" user agent and got same response.

So your SEO tools are seeing this instead of the real site, and that explains the mystery.

But it also means it's not a programming issue, and therefore off-topic for stackoverflow, your question might get deleted. Unless maybe you are hosting yourself, and that initial page is controlled by a server-side script of yours... Or maybe your `.htaccess` (which I just noticed in the tags). I wonder if that question should be migrated to [webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) site.

Comment: I see, I used a free hosting service provider. Maybe that's their antibot measure.

Comment: If you need help about how to deal with this, I suppose you should ask a follow-up question to [webmasters stackexchange community](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/), where you'll reach better experts. In any case you've confirmed that this question has not much to do with programming. I'm not sure what's best here for stackoverflow, if you should [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it to signal there's nothing more to do here, or if it can be migrated, or simply deleted (if you can do that, go ahead).